# Block Facebook, But allow Oauth

Tags: macos, blocking, facebook

I would like to edit my Mac OSX hosts file to block facebook. The only problem with doing this is I need to use facebook connect to use some of my Spotify apps.

I also use a program called self control to edit the file.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you can.  Editing your host file will make facebook.com and www.facebook.com resolve somewhere else. [Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) requires that you connect to www.facebook.com for OAuth authentication.  Google offers OAuth.